# Error al hacer peticion a Heroku

Tags: nodejs, express, heroku

Subi mi servidor **node/express** a **Heroku**. Tambien en **Heroku** tengo una base de datos **postgres** de la cual estoy conectado con **pgAdmin 4** de forma local.
Desde **pgAdmin 4** cuando escribo la **query** por ejemplo **SELECT * FROM users**, me devuelve la respuesta, pero cuando utilizo **Insomnia** para hacer la petición a **Heroku** me devuelve un **status 500** con el mensaje **"Internal server error"**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Evidentemente hay un error pero no se en donde podria estar, a continuacion muestro las configuraciones de mis archivos.

**asi tengo las carpetas**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca **users.controller** con la **funcion getUsers()**, donde deberia devolver todos los usuarios.

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { QueryResult } from 'pg'
import { pool } from '../database'

export const getUsers = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> => {
    try {
        const response: QueryResult = await pool.query('SELECT * from users order by username asc');
        return res.status(200).json(response.rows);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return res.status(500).json('Internal server error');
    }
}
```

Aca la ruta en **user.routes.ts**

```js
import { Router } from 'express'

const router = Router();

import { getUsers } from '../controllers/user.controller'

router.get('/users', getUsers); // get todos los usuarios

export default router;
```

aca el archivo **database.ts**, con los datos que me dió **Heroku** para hacer la conexion.

```js
import { Pool } from 'pg'

export const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'datos de heroku',
    host: 'datos de heroku',
    password: 'datos de heroku',
    database: 'datos de heroku',
    port: 5432
})
```

Aca **package.json** completo, por si hay algo que le falte:

```js
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"tsc --watch\" \"nodemon dist/server.js\"",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/pg": "^7.14.5",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mercadopago": "^1.5.5",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "pg": "^8.4.0",
    "stripe": "^8.126.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  }
}
```

aca el **archivo server**

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config(); // aca lee las variables de entorno para el token 

import express from 'express'
var multer  = require('multer')
const uuid = require('uuid')
const app = express(); // inicializo express
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
 
//rutas
import userRoutes from './routes/user.routes'

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(userRoutes);

app.use(express.static('public')); // Carpeta public la hago de acceso publica. para poder ver las imagenes desde el navegador

// Configuro el puerto. Tomo el puerto del sistema operativo o el 3000
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// Inicio el servidor
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('usuarios server on port:', app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El **view logs** de **Heroku** estaba mostrando esto:

```js
2021-03-17T22:31:14.768515+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: self signed certificate
2021-03-17T22:31:14.768519+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34)
2021-03-17T22:31:14.768521+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2021-03-17T22:31:14.768521+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8)
2021-03-17T22:31:14.768521+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12) {
2021-03-17T22:31:14.768522+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
2021-03-17T22:31:14.768523+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Aparentemente **Heroku Postgres** utiliza certificados autofirmados por seguridad, esto me impedia acceder a la base de datos. La solucion fue **desactivar la verificación del certificado SSL** agregando esta linea **ssl: { "rejectUnauthorized": false }** a mi archivo **database.ts**

```js
import { Pool } from 'pg'

export const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'ohcmjxflybhuxs',
    host: 'ec2-54-90-13-87.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
    password: '87a7776853846d79ec4826d8f7c8a7a4b7d1cb6a1b94f13d88a34a06ebe93d30',
    database: 'd6mtnl8db77ln6',
    ssl: { "rejectUnauthorized": false },
    port: 5432
})
```